# SSH and Port Forwarding - what are the possible attacks and how to avoid them?

Tags: attacks, ssh, threats, port-forwarding

What are possible attacks when using SSH and Local or Remote Port Forwarding? What are the threats? I understand that there are many, but what are they? And also, how could they be avoided?

Comment: This question is overly broad.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about exposing your local ssh to the public internet:

Anyone can start trying to login with any username and password, essentially trying to bruteforce your account.

If you only allow public/private key authentication this reduces your risk greatly